# Working in Rust with signers across threads -- T: Signer + Send + Sync

Tags: rust, solana-sdk, signer, shadow-drive

I'm working with the Shadow Drive Rust SDK and would like to pass a `Box<dyn Signer>` to it (I'd like to allow for keypair, remote wallet, or presign), which requires that I wrap it order to make it `Send + Sync`.

My attempt below:

```
pub struct ThreadsafeSigner {
    pub inner: Arc<RwLock<Box<dyn Signer>>>,
}

impl Clone for ThreadsafeSigner {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: Arc::clone(&self.inner),
        }
    }
}

impl Signer for ThreadsafeSigner {
    fn try_pubkey(&self) -> Result<Pubkey, SignerError> {
        Ok(self.inner.read().unwrap().pubkey())
    }

    fn try_sign_message(&self, message: &[u8]) -> Result<Signature, SignerError> {
        self.inner.read().unwrap().try_sign_message(message)
    }

    fn is_interactive(&self) -> bool {
        self.inner.read().unwrap().is_interactive()
    }
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't work with:

```
let threadsafe_signer = ThreadsafeSigner {
        inner: Arc::new(RwLock::new(signer))
    };
let shdw_drive_client = ShadowDriveClient::new(threadsafe_signer, "https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net");
```

Here's the compiler error:

```
let shdw_drive_client = ShadowDriveClient::new(threadsafe_signer, "https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net");
   |                             ---------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `(dyn solana_sdk::signer::Signer + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |                             |
   |                             required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `Send` is not implemented for `(dyn solana_sdk::signer::Signer + 'static)`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `Unique<(dyn solana_sdk::signer::Signer + 'static)>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Box<(dyn solana_sdk::signer::Signer + 'static)>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Sync` for `std::sync::RwLock<Box<(dyn solana_sdk::signer::Signer + 'static)>>`
   = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `Arc<std::sync::RwLock<Box<(dyn solana_sdk::signer::Signer + 'static)>>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `ThreadsafeSigner`
note: required by a bound in `ShadowDriveClient::<T>::new`
  --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/shadow-drive-rust-0.3.0/src/client.rs:59:17
   |
59 |     T: Signer + Send + Sync,
   |                 ^^^^ required by this bound in `ShadowDriveClient::<T>::new`
```

I'm unclear on what I'm doing wrong, and what the right approach is here.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach as of now is to just create the Signer in each thread separately, instead of having a single signer being used across threads.